# C# Add Record to DataBound DataGridView with textboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview, ssms

I'm new to the whole C# database thing. I made a database in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 and then connected it to a DataGrid (in Windows Forms) by choosing the DataSource from DataGridView Tasks in Visual C#. 
What I want to do is to fill in texboxes with new record data and then press a button that adds the textbox information to a new row in the DataGrid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to add to DataGrid or Database? Did you try to write any code?

Comment: I want the information to be added to the database so that the DataGrid also shows the new record. I've tried getting help from other answers but so far, no luck.

Comment: did you try adding `InsertCommand` and `Insertparameters` to `DataSource`?

Comment: No I haven't and I'm not really sure how to.

Comment: Oneeb you get get any one row in the text boxes. and then what do you want to do with the data in the textbox that you would obtain from datagrid view??

Comment: What I mean is that I want to insert a record into a new row in my DataGrid which also updates the database behind it. The record data will be entered into a few text boxes and then a button will be pressed to add that data to the grid.

Comment: What i understand you first want to retrieve the data from database in gridview. now suppose you got five rows from the database in the datagrid view, then having done it you want to add a new 6th row in the gridview from the text box. right??

Comment: Yes exactly! There are 6 columns and five textboxes. One of them is an autofill column. I've already retrieved the database in gridview and have all existing records in the datagrid. I used a wizard to create a dataset and then filled the gridview with the dataset. But now I'm having trouble adding a new row with information from the textboxes.

Comment: now plzz tell me one more thing. do you want to update the database with the values in the textbox as well. or you just want to display them in the row of gridview

Comment: Yes I want the database updated with the new values as well as the datagridview. Here's a picture of my form to paint a clearer picture by the way: http://i49.tinypic.com/24bkihi.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you probably want.
Create a Table in your sql server database as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentInfo](
    [StudentId] [numeric](2, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SName] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [FName] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [Class] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_StudentInfo] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StudentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now use this coding in your windows application to update delete and save data in the created table

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataGrid.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.DataGrid_CellClick);
        }
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("data source=localhost;initial catalog=acc;integrated security=true");
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TBStudentID.Enabled = false;
            GetData();
        }
        private void GetData()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from StudentInfo", cn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            DataGrid.DataSource = dt;
        }
        private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into StudentInfo(SName, FName, Class) values('" + TBSName.Text + "','" + TBFName.Text + "','" + TBClass.Text + "')", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            GetData();
        }
        // using this CellClick event you will be able to get the selected row values
        // in Respective TextBoxes by clicking any of the datagridview rows
        private void DataGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                TBStudentID.Text = DataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                TBSName.Text = DataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                TBFName.Text = DataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                TBClass.Text = DataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
        private void TextBoxClear()
        {
            TBStudentID.Text = null;
            TBSName.Text = null;
            TBFName.Text = null;
            TBClass.Text = null;
        }
        private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from StudentInfo where StudentId = '" + TBStudentID.Text + "'", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            GetData();
            TextBoxClear();
        }

        private void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update StudentInfo set SName = '" + TBSName.Text + "', FName = '" + TBFName.Text + "', Class = '" + TBClass.Text + "' where StudentId = '" + TBStudentID.Text + "'", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            GetData();
            TextBoxClear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for getting the Form_Load event you just need to right click the form and then click view code

Comment: yes you can show it in gridview as well. it dosn't make any difference whether a columns has an auto increment key or not. but when you will add the last row from textboxes then in your id columns of datagridview you have to add empty value and then the other five text box's values that will complete your six columns.

Comment: @OneebMalik it don'st save automatically. actually you are doing it in a wrong way. the right way of doing it is to first update database with the values of text boxes and then retrieving data from database to grid view. but I just was helping you do what you were trying for.

Comment: @OneebMalik would you like me to tell you how to do that. and further I would request you to delete your previous comments.

Comment: Hmm. Okay. Whenever you have time in the next few days, I would be really glad if you could show me how to update the database with the textboxes and then retrieving that data from the database. I'm really new to this so it was a little confusing. Thanks again for your help! Alhamdulillah I've learned a lot today.

Comment: hmm its ok. but I would update my answer as I just suggested. But not today. I would do that tomorrow Insha Allah

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making use of the onrowdatabound method of your grid view in conjunction with a templatefield

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview" OnRowDataBound="grd_OnRowDataBound">
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("data value") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then create the method in the back end as follows

```
 protected void grd_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
             TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("id");
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure how to use the asp code. I did my project in Windows Forms by the way, not on a web page.

Comment: ok oneeb i would tell you how to get a row from a datagrid view in the textbox. will it be all for you?

Comment: I would really appreciate it, but I don't want a row from the datagrid in the textbox. I want the textbox values insterted into the datagrid

Answer (score 0):

You can try the concept of the following. Please see my notes on no. 3 as well.

```
public Form1()
{
    ds = new DataSet();
    // 1. Create connection.
    conn = new OleDbConnection(@"connection_string.");
    // 2. init SqlDataAdapter with select command and connection
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from YouRtable", conn);

    // 3. fill in insert, update, and delete commands 

       (For No. 3 - You can search around the internet on how to construct a SQL Command). You can refer the values that you to insert from the textboxes that you have.)

    OleDbCommandBuilder cmdBldr = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
    da.Fill(ds, "YouRtable");
    dataGridView2.DataSource = ds;
    dataGridView2.DataMember = "YouRtable";
}

//Here is your save/update button code.
private void btnSaveGridData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    da.Update(ds, "YouRtable");
}
```